# Why are these 'max' functions not working?

Tags: javascript, function, max

The task is to make a **function** in JavaScript that **outputs the max value inside an array**.
If the array is empty, return *undefined*.
I was provided a solution, but it doesn't work either.

My first attempt failed. After 1 cycle in the loop, the value of **max** becomes *undefined*.

**NOT WORKING:**

```
function getMax(array) {
  return array.reduce((max,current) =>
  {if (current>max) max=current})
}
```

After this, I tried again, and thankfully, this time it works perfectly. Great, job done.

**WORKS:**

```
function getMax(array) {
  let max=array[0];
  for (let value of array)
    if (value>max)
        max=value;
  return max;
}
```

I then checked the solution I was provided , which is meant to work, but surprisingly it does not, and suffers from the same problem as my first attempt.

**NOT WORKING:**

```
function getMax(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) return undefined;
  array.reduce((a, b) => (a > b) ? a : b);
}
```

Why is it behaving like this?

Answer (score 4):

What `.reduce` does is, for every element of the array, the callback is called. The first argument is the value returned from the *last* callback, or the initial value (2nd parameter of `.reduce` - or, first item of the array, if no initial value was provided). The second argument in the callback is the array item being iterated over.

The whole `.reduce` evaluates to the value returned from the callback on the final iteration.

So, in the first code

```
function getMax(array) {
  return array.reduce((max,current) =>
  {if (current>max) max=current})
}
```

because you never return a value from the callback, the accumulator (the first argument, `max`) is always undefined, and nothing gets returned to outside the `.reduce` either. (Reassigning a variable, by itself, almost never has any side effects.)

Another problem with this is that it'll throw an error if the array is empty; check if the array is empty before entering the `.reduce`, like you do elsewhere.

---

The third code

```
function getMax(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) return undefined;
  array.reduce((a, b) => (a > b) ? a : b);
}
```

doesn't work because you didn't `return` the result - the whole `.reduce` is just an unused expression.